# Python Convex optimization

Tags: optimization, python

Hi I am looking for a robust convex optimization problem solver in python. My problem isn't very complex, its basically a simple constrained qp program. I am using Enthought free python 2.7 distribution on a windows 64 bit machine.

I came across http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html

It doesn't seem very easy to install this on windows. I also came across Mosek, which seems a bit of a overkill.

Does anyone know of a good solution, do people use cvxopt on windows?

Comment: CVXopt should be more than powerful enough for your optimization problem and linux is free. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

CVXPY http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/index.html is another CVX family member (all inspired by the original CVX, which runs under MATLAB, but developed by different developers).

CVXPY should be easy to install under WINDOWS.  CVXOPT was written as more or less a personal research code, which has been made available to the public. So it is not as friendly, as you have discovered, in the installation process. I believe CVXPY is under more active development than CVXOPT.

All of these modeling frameworks for disciplined convex programming (DCP) rely on solver(s) to actually solve the problem. They serve as powerful and friendly front ends to the solvers.  In the case of CVXOPT, there are internal solvers.  And these, along with other solvers, may actually be invoked from CVXPY.